# Angular CDK Layout - How to include BreakPointObserver globally across the project

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am setting up a new project with latest Angular.I am using Angular Material for this. I am using `BreakpointObserver` from `@angular/cdk/layout`.
I am able to add that succesfully to one of my component.But I want to add it globally to my project so that all the components/modules can use web/tablet/mobile breakpoints for different DOM manipulation.

I am able to add that to the app.component.ts , but I am expecting to write a directive or something. Not service because `BreakpointObserver` is already a  service.

What would be the best approach to add BreakPointObserver observables globally in the project. Do not want to add isHandset$ observables everytime in each component's ts file

Comment: adding a directive will help ?

Comment: This is also my question!

Comment: Logically, each component must respond individually to the observer, so there is no way to _not_ have each component individually "observe" the breakpoint(s) or at least implement different breakpoint behaviours. You _could_ have all of your components extend a common base class that does the observing - but your individual components would still have to implement something - possibly just style. You could also have only the base application component observe the breakpoints and apply global CSS classes so that your components are affected.

Comment: what is your objective ? to use inside template mainly? or to avoid an injection into TS? Maybe https://github.com/angular/flex-layout could be a good complementary solution.

Comment: why not use another service that extends BreakPointObserver behaviour?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is this cdkObserveContent directive 
 https://material.angular.io/cdk/observers/overview

Answer (score 1):

I think your idea of using some kind of custom directive would be a good solution. For example, in the case you want to add/remove components of the DOM, you could define only one structural directive that handle adding/removing its host, depending on the viewport dimension using the `BreakpointObserver` service.

To accomplish that you could define something like this:

```js
@Directive({
    selector: '[contentForSmallScreen]'
})
export class ContentForSmallScreenDirective implements OnDestroy  {

  constructor(
     private templateReference: TemplateRef<any>,
     private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
     private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver
  ) {
      this.breakpointObserver
          .observe([tablet,mobile])
          .pipe(pluck('matches'), distinctUntilChanged())
          .subscribe(this.showHideHost);  
  }

  private showHideHost = (matches: boolean) => {
      matches 
          ? this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateReference)
          : this.viewContainerRef.clear();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.breakpointObserver.ngOnDestroy();
  }
}
```

And then after declare it at your NgModule, it can be used with any component/html element you wanna add/remove from the DOM depending on if the viewport's dimension meet the tablet and mobile viewport specs.

```html
<app-any-component *contentForSmallScreen></app-any-component>
```

‍ [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u7ujwj?file=src/app/content-for-small-screen.directive.ts)